# Solve a Quadratic map

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I read [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) on Wolfram Alpha. It states that:
a quadratic recurrence relation uses a second degree polynomial to express $x_{n+1}$ as a function of $x_n$.  A "quadratic map", then, is a recurrence relation:
$$S_{n+1} = a S_n^2 + b S_n + c$$
My question is if,
$$S_0=d$$
what is$$\sum_{i=1}^nS_i-S_{i-1}=?$$
I was wondering is there a **closed form** for this? How to solve this? I have been trying z-transform and method of undetermined coefficients, but no progress.

Comment: Isn't this just $S_n - S_1$?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Yes but how do you propose to get $S_n$ without computing $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: I have no idea. Before this it was $x_n$ in the first equation and I might have misinterpreted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you begin with $S_{n+1} = a S_n^2 + b S_n + c,$ define $T_n$ so that
$$  S_n = \frac{1}{a} \left( T_n - \frac{b}{2} \right),   $$
$$  T_n = a S_n + \frac{b}{2}.  $$
The outcome is that
$$  T_{n+1} = T_n^2 + \left( \frac{b}{2} + ac - \frac{b^2}{4} \right).  $$

You can absorb your coefficient $a$ into the variable by a multiplication ($\sqrt a$ somewhere) and eliminate $b$ by a translation. When done, you have $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + c.$  These have predictable behavior as far as size.

however, there are only two cases that can be solved in closed form: if
$$\color{green}{y_{n+1} = y_n^2 ,}$$ then
$$\color{green}{  y_n = y_0^{\left( 2^n \right)}}. $$

If $\color{magenta}{x_0 > 2}$ and
$$\color{magenta}{x_{n+1} = x_n^2 -2 ,}$$ then
$$  \color{magenta}{x_n = A^{\left( 2^n \right)} + B^{\left( 2^n \right)},} $$
with 
$$ \color{magenta}{ A = \frac{x_0 + \sqrt{x_0^2 - 4}}{2},}  $$
$$ \color{magenta}{ B = \frac{x_0 - \sqrt{x_0^2 - 4}}{2}.}  $$
Note that $\color{magenta}{A+B = x_0}$ and $\color{magenta}{AB = 1.}$

For any other value of the constant $c,$ one can find and approximate value for the larger $A,$ just take logarithm of the recurrence, but no explicit formula. The case with $c=-2$ comes under the heading of Lucas Sequences, and is instrumental in the Lucas-Lehmer primality test.

Comment: I've been trying to show the result you gave in pink, but I think it requires methods I'm unfamiliar with. Could you point me to a resource?

Comment: @MattR., once you know the result in this form, proof is just induction on $n.$  $AB=1,$ and any $A^k B^k = 1.$ Some background material is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence but is not needed for this proof.

Comment: That's certainly true, but I don't like pulling results out of thin air :D

Comment: @MattR., I had answered with these results several times over the years, and will not be able to find the first question that got me looking into this. I think the pink fact above is equivalent to the line in the table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Other_relations that says $$  V_{2n} = V_n^2 - 2 Q^n$$ but, as I say, it has been a long time.

Comment: I will look into it myself some more, but thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I don't see how to "eliminate $b$ by a translation." can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChaoXu, edited in